Looking for open source food delivery platform
I'm currently setting up an e-commerce system for food and beverages and am looking for the best open-source platform to manage it, as I'm planning to use it for a franchise and would prefer not to pay ongoing fees. I found restoapp, which looks promising, but I would like to explore more alternatives before making a decision.
Some key features I'm looking for:

Easy integration with POS systems
Support for online payments
Ability to customize the app or website (for example, branding and unique features for different franchise locations)
User-friendly order management (intuitive dashboards for kitchen and delivery staff)
Flexible delivery options (like pickup, delivery scheduling, or third-party services)
Must support mobile apps (both iPhone and Android)
Open-source (critical, as I want to avoid fees and fully control the system for franchising purposes)

Any recommendations for platforms that meet these needs would be greatly appreciated!

You may want to look at Erpnext. It will require customization but it is appropriate to the scaling of a franchise.
Here's the code: https://github.com/frappe/erpnext

Your proposal is very interesting, but it's not exactly what we need. We're looking for a system that will not only manage a store, website, and application, but also handle order management.

It includes Sales Order (quotation, order, invoice, payment...) > https://docs.erpnext.com/docs/user/manual/en/sales-order
